# When a "open in new tab" link is clicked in a WebView element, it opens a popup window

Tags: electron

So I am trying to stop the action of a new window opening whenever I click a link that "opens in a new tab" inside of a webview element, like this:

I would like to grab the url when the link is clicked, and prevent it from opening in a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by using a combination of preload and [webContents.setWindowOpenHandler](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssetwindowopenhandlerhandler)

main.js

```js
 mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ ... }) // the browserwindow code

  mainWindow.webContents.on("did-attach-webview", (_, contents) => {
    contents.setWindowOpenHandler((details) => {
      mainWindow.webContents.send('open-url', details.url);
      return { action: 'deny' }
    })
  })
```

Preload.js

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', {
    send: (channel, data) => ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, data),
    handle: (channel, callable, event, data) => ipcRenderer.on(channel, callable(event, data))
})
```

Renderer.js

```js
  window.api.handle(
    "open-url",
    (event, data) =>
      function (event, data) {
        document.querySelector("webview").src = data // your webview element
      },
    event
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

To stop the action of a new tab/window opening and define your own behavior in Electron, you can use the webview element's `new-window` event and call `preventDefault()` on the event object.

```js
const { webContents } = require('electron')

webview.addEventListener('new-window', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const url = event.url
  // Grab the URL here ...
});
```

This prevents the new tab/window from opening and allows you to define your own behavior such as grabbing the URL.

### Method 2

You could alternatively use the `webview.addEventListener` method to listen for the `did-start-loading event`, and then use the `webview.executeJavaScript` method to inject a script that prevents the link from opening in a new tab/window.

```js
...

webview.addEventListener('did-start-loading', function() {
  webview.executeJavaScript(`
    document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if (event.target.tagName === 'A' && event.target.target === '_blank') {
        event.preventDefault()
        // Grab the URL here ...
      }
    })
  `)
})
```

This will listen for a click event for links set to `_blank`, and stop them from opening in a new tab/window.

Comment: It seems that the "new-window" event does not register, and it is not in the [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/webview-tag#methods). i would like to use this, but I can't find anything about it. And for the second method, this only helps with `a` elements that have the tag target=href. I would like it to be for all new window events.

Comment: @notAperson535 yes, it has been changed. Check [`webContents.setWindowOpenHandler`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssetwindowopenhandlerhandler) which is essentially the same

Comment: Yes, I actually saw that myself, and I was able to use preload and a go function in combination with that to fix my problem, see the answer below